# Writing a k8s client - which one to use

Tags: kubernetes

Starting to learn and write cli clients for kubernetes, which one to use:

1. https://github.com/kubernetes-client/go
   or older and maybe deprecated at some point:
2. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go

If starting now, which one to bet on?

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinion based question so the answer is an opinion:

Use the official Kubernetes go client: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go